# Tailwind: how to access the variables/configs in SCSS files

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

Since I changed the default breakpoints of Tailwindcss, I wonder how can I access the breakpoints in my own SCSS files?

**tailwind.config.js** (default breakpoints)

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'sm': '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      'md': '768px',
      // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

      'lg': '1024px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

      'xl': '1280px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }

      '2xl': '1536px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1536px) { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

Is that possible to access the configs as a SCSS variable from **tailwind.config.js** like below?

```
@import 'tailwind/base';

@media (min-width: $sm) { <--- use $sm here which is from tailwind.config.js instead of specific value
    html {
        width: 100vw;
    }
}
@media (min-width: $md) {
    html {
        width: 80vw;
    }
}
@media (min-width: $lg) {
    html {
        width: 60vw;
    }
}
```

Is that possible? I googled it but nothing helped (most are how to get tailwind configs in js files).

Thanks a lot for any helps!

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @avia sorry for my poor English, I've modified the question

Comment: Ah, you want to refer to another stylesheet *inside* a stylesheet. Example inside stylesheet 1, call a variable A that would contain the value X from stylesheet 2?

Comment: I believe it's possible, I have done similar things but in regular CSS, using PHP. I'm not sure if SCSS accepts that kind of stuff.

Comment: @DengSihan I would like to know why you want to include in a SCSS file?

Comment: @DengSihan You can direactly access into css, for scss you have to some configurations, please check following link for more details: https://dev.to/philw_/using-style-dictionary-to-transform-tailwind-config-into-scss-variables-css-custom-properties-and-javascript-via-design-tokens-24h5